# Problems with allocating memory in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, allocation

Quite sadly I have to admit that I have been trying to teach myself c++ for some time but I have been really confused when it comes to pointers.

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work? I don't get any segmentation faults. It compiles I just get nothing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
int main(){
  void *buffer = new char[8];
  memset( (char*)&buffer, 'a', sizeof(buffer) );
  std::cout << (char*)buffer <<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are unlucky. I got [Segmentation Fault](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/TTXCDsmsZoTf5mDv).

Comment: Try removing the & from buffer. It's already a pointer. You are taking the **address** of the pointer.

Comment: Odd, I wonder if it has to do with the way my compiler is optimized.

Comment: "*I don't get any segmentation faults. It compiles I just get nothing.*"  -- Once of the first (or earliest) things you must realize when writing C++ code is that 1) code that compiles ok doesn't mean the program is ok, and 2) C++ has a concept called **undefined behavior**.  That is what you're code is exhibiting.

Comment: I tried removing the &. Exact same behaviour.

Comment: @mreff555 Did you read the documentation on `memset`?  What does the third parameter to `memset` denote?  That answers why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Paul, Good point, and yes I am aware that it isn't functioning correctly. This is definitely a case of undefined behaviour. I just don't understand why.

Comment: Also note that `sizeof(buffer)` returns the size of `buffer` itself, not size of the allocated region pointed by `buffer`.

Comment: Paul, I did. I just looked at it again and I guess I'm not understanding what you are getting at. If it makes any difference I originally had 8  for the third argument and got the same behavior.

Comment: Mike, so are you saying it should be sizeof(buffer - 1)?

Comment: Change your code to allocate 1,000 bytes.  What is `sizeof(buffer)`?  Will it be 1,000?

Comment: No. `sizeof(buffer - 1)` return the size of `buffer - 1`, which shouldn't be what you want. You cannot use `sizeof` operator to determint the size of allocated region. Save the size somewhere else if you want it.

Comment: Ok, I guess that makes sense. I guess the sizeof wouldn't work since it's a void type and an allocated region and doesn't really have a size right? So why doesn't it work when I just put in 8?

Comment: The `sizeof` tells you the number of bytes that a type occupies.  So all you did was say `sizeof(void *)`, which is usually 4 or 8.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie and MikeCAT: I am glad to see you both trying to teach and not just rushing to post an answer. Great job!

Comment: OK, I changed it back to memset( (char*)buffer, 'a', 8 );. but I'm still getting the same behaviour. If this was the only issue I can't understand why this wouldn't work.

Comment: @mreff555 There are multiple issues with your code.  The answers cover most of them, with the one (so far) not mentioned is that you failed to call `delete []  buffer;`.  Even though this is a toy program, don't get into the bad habit of allocating memory and not concern yourself of deallocating it.

Comment: Guys, thanks for all of you comments. I did manage to get it working when Isolated the code. It looks like the problem in my program must be elsewhere. but at least I now understand what I was doing wrong with memset. and yes I added in delete[]. Like you said paul, it was a toy program and I was being lazy.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do here, this isn't the right way to do it at all in C++

Comment: M.M. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the following problems.

**Problem 1**

```
memset( (char*)&buffer, 'a', sizeof(buffer) );
```

That's the wrong address to pass to `memset`. You need to use:

```
memset( buffer, 'a', sizeof(buffer) );
```

**Problem 2**

`sizeof(buffer)` evaluates to the size of a pointer (4 for 32 bit platforms and 8 for 64 bit platforms). You need to use the length of the array, which is `8`.

```
memset( buffer, 'a', 8 );
```

**Problem 3**

```
std::cout << (char*)buffer <<std::endl;
```

will work only if `buffer` is a null terminated string. If you use `memset`, all the valid memory is set to `a`. Hence, the string is not null terminated.

You need to make sure that `buffer` is null terminated.

```
buffer[7] = '\0';
std::cout << buffer <<std::endl; // No need for explicit cast
```

Comment: Thanks R Sahu. As far as "Problem 3" goes I was actually trying to prevent a null terminated string. However, I was not aware cout wouldn't work under those conditions. Is there a way to print type specified information that is not null terminated, assuming I know how large it should be?

Answer (score 0):

1. You copy into the address of `buffer`. But `buffer` holds the address of the buffer. So you're copying into the address of the address.
2. The `<<` operator on a `char *` only works for C-style strings. You can't use it on arbitrary arrays of characters that aren't strings. How would it know how many characters to output?
3. The `sizeof` operator only tells you the size of a type.

Answer (score -1):

Void pointers are quite tricky and are usually not used.  I would just make it a char * pointer and not use the reference of buffer.  The name of the pointer is the reference of the whole memory location.

Here is a nice reference for the memset function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/

Best of luck.  Looks like you have it working most of the way.

Comment: Did you mean void pointer and not Null pointer? Either way, their use is common in the right context.

Comment: I did, whoops.  I'll edit that.  Null pointers on the brain.  Thanks Brian.